# How to make a bone translate on a tilted Axis?

Tags: bones, constraints

So, I've started a new project and i've come across this problem:

I have this rather simple armature composed of 4 bones:
-**Rotation**: which is stationary and rotates on one of the three main axes *(x,y or z)*.
-**RotationArm**: child of **Rotation** and inherits the rotation
-**RotationArmPos**: child of **RotationArm** and only inherits the position
-**Target**: child of **RorationArmPos** and it's not connected to him

[image: bones in rig]

My objective is to be able to move the **Target** bone along the immaginary tilted axis, going through the two ends of the bone, based on the vertical translation of the **RotationArmPos**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set up the rig that you're looking for, you can use the Transformation constraint on the **Target** bone. Using your set up, you would use the following steps:

1. Select the **RotationArmPos** bone.
2. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+select the **Target** bone.
3. Add a Transformation Constraint (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>→Transformation).
4. In Bone Constraints, find the Transformation constraint that you just added. Make the following adjustments:

   - For the Source, set the Max Y value to 1.000. Leave all of the other numbers the same.
   - For the Destination, do the same.
   - For the Space drop-down menus, set your Source space to *Local with Parent*. Set your Destination space to *Local Space* as well.
   - At the top of the Transformation Constraint, enable the Extrapolate checkbox. This ensures that movement happens beyond the values you entered for the Y-axis on the Source and Destination.
5. Now, when you rotate the **Rotation** bone about its local Y-axis (in your image, that's also the global Y-axis), the **Target** bone will move along its own local Y-axis. Since **RotationArmPos** is a connected child of **RotationArm**, its Y-axis values are only going to go in the negative direction, so you should expect the **Target** bone to move towards its head as you rotate. From here you can tweak values to get the behavior your want. You may even want to remove the parenting of **Target** from **RotationArmPos**.

[image]

This constraint gives you a lot of flexibility. In fact, if the **Rotation** bone is your primary controller, you could even drive **Target** directly from that bone's rotation and skip using the **RotationArmPos** bone's position altogether.

I've put [an example .blend file](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/42773) on pasteall.org.

Answer (score 0):

Change the *Transform Orientation* in the panel at the bottom of the *3D Viewport* from *Global* to *Normal*.

[image] --> [image]

*The Procedure:*

[image]